# Science fiction short story about lost group of mechanics

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The main character lives on a sparsely populated world, where everyone goes to school to become mechanics, only they have lost the knowledge of why they are learning, so they are all skilled at something they don't understand

Meanwhile, outside in the rest of the galaxy there are almost no working spaceships, and we follow a new character tasked with finding new ones to salvage she lands on the planet and ends up taking the other character with him in his ship, the guy ends up fixing his ship, I specifically remember him fixing the air conditioner on the ship. The pilot realizes that his side of the Galactic conflict now has a way to fix all of their ships and I think that's where it ends.

I remember reading the story around 2012, but it is most likely from an anthology, possibly from the 80s or 90s

Comment: Hi! See [our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) to improve your question. First, when did you read it?

Comment: I read it maybe 7 years ago, i'm thinking it was old then, though, i most likely read it in an anthology from the 80s/90s

Comment: It sounds a great deal like Theodore Cogswell's "Spectre General."

Answer (score 2):

Mark Olson found it, thanks a ton! It's definitely "the specter general" by Theodore Cogswell